# Tracking which apps used Camera, contacts, email, voice, etc without root

Tags: android, email, camera, contacts

Is it possible to implement an application that reports which apps used Camera, contacts, email, voice, and photos without ROOT?

Also does such app need any permissions??

I have searched about it, but I only got results about the Camera. Isn't there anyway around it to get to know which apps used it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to implement an application that reports which apps used Camera, contacts, email, voice, and photos without ROOT?

No.